# What is the best way to propagate Argument Validation Error in Swift?

Tags: swift, error-handling, api-design

Is there a standard way to propagate error from the function that the given argument is invalid in Swift?

I know I can define ErrorType by myself. But if there's standard way I want to avoid duplicated effort.

Another options is make return type nullable.
(Personally I prefer throwing error since with try? we can get same effect.)

What way is regarded as 'Standard' or 'Good' in Swift?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you can `throw` any NSError, which is slightly more "standard" than defining your own ErrorType.

Comment: I see. I thought there's no standard codes in NSError but now I found that there's some [codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSError_Codes) defined in cocoa domain.
NSError with cocoa domain and NSValidationErrorMinimum code would be an good candidate.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the same to tell the developers who use my code that something went wrong. Be accurate because it will stop the application.

```
class AbstractMethodException: NSException {
    init() {
        super.init(
            name: "Called an abstract method",
            reason: "All abstract methods must be overriden by subclasses",
            userInfo: nil)
    }
    //required by Xcode compiler. strange thing
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

And there is an example of usage how to raise an exaption for abstract function.

```
func update(withData data: PVModel) {
        AbstractMethodException().raise()
}
```

If just throw error required i would recommend to use ErrorType protocol.

Comment: Thank you.  
I modified the title since it was confusing.  

From you post I found that I can use NSException.raise and NSInvalidArgumentException in Swift.  

They are not converted to ErrorType and just causes SIGABRT as you've mentioned.  
In my case ErrorType seems better since there's a option to let app to crash or handle it by catch/ optional substitution.

Comment: @Satoshi yes. that's how abstract function should work. just causes SIGABRT.